# JWT Validation in Azure Function V2

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-active-directory, azure-functions

I am trying to implement JWT token validation in Azure Function V2 using azure AD . However I am getting this error below

**IDX10501: Signature validation failed. Unable to match keys: 
kid: 'BB8CeFVqyaGrGNuehJIiL4dfjzw**',

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here

Here is my code

```
public class AccessTokenProvider : IAccessTokenProvider
    {
        private const string AUTH_HEADER_NAME   = "Authorization";
        private const string BEARER_PREFIX      = "Bearer ";
        private readonly string _audience;
        private readonly string _issuer;
        private readonly bool _enabled;

        public AccessTokenProvider(bool enabled , string audience, string issuer)
        {
            _enabled        = enabled;
            _audience       = audience;
            _issuer         = issuer;
        }

        public AccessTokenResult ValidateToken(HttpRequest request)
        {
            try
            {
                if(!_enabled)
                {
                    return AccessTokenResult.Success(null);
                }
                // Get the token from the header
                if (request != null &&
                    request.Headers.ContainsKey(AUTH_HEADER_NAME) &&
                    request.Headers[AUTH_HEADER_NAME].ToString().StartsWith(BEARER_PREFIX))
                {
                     var sharedKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Convert.FromBase64String("PublicKey"));
                     var token = request.Headers[AUTH_HEADER_NAME].ToString().Substring(BEARER_PREFIX.Length);
                    // Create the parameters
                    var tokenParams = new TokenValidationParameters()
                    {
                        RequireSignedTokens         = true,
                        ValidAudience               = _audience,
                        ValidateAudience            = true,
                        ValidIssuer                 = _issuer,
                        ValidateIssuer              = true,
                        ValidateIssuerSigningKey    = true,
                        ValidateLifetime            = true,
                        IssuerSigningKey            = sharedKey
                    };

                    // Validate the token
                    var handler     = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

                    var result      = handler.ValidateToken(token, tokenParams, out var securityToken);
                    return AccessTokenResult.Success(result);
                }
                else
                {
                    return AccessTokenResult.NoToken();
                }
            }
            catch (SecurityTokenExpiredException)
            {
                return AccessTokenResult.Expired();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return AccessTokenResult.Error(ex);
            }
        }
```

I have this code in my Startup.cs

```
private static void RegisterJwtTokenValidation(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // Get the configuration files for the OAuth token issuer
            var audience        = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Authentication.Audiences");
            var issuer          = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Authentication.Issuer");
            var authEnabled     = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Authentication.Enabled");

            if (!bool.TryParse(authEnabled, out bool isAuthEnabled))
            {
                isAuthEnabled = false;
            }

            // Register the access token provider as a singleton
            services.AddSingleton<IAccessTokenProvider, AccessTokenProvider>(s => new AccessTokenProvider(isAuthEnabled, audience, issuer));
        }
```

Note: Code reference https://www.ben-morris.com/custom-token-authentication-in-azure-functions-using-bindings/

Comment: seems to be an encryption issue related to the content of your shared key. I hope you've replaced var sharedKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Convert.FromBase64String("PublicKey")); with the real public key, otherwise, that is the problem.

Comment: There is an out of the box solution: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-authentication-authorization. Does that not fit your scenario ?

Comment: @Thomas. Thanks ..Didnt realise that there is an out of box solution. It works very well. Please add this as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on your use case, you may want to use the out of the box authentication mechanism for App Services:

- [Authentication and authorization in Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-authentication-authorization)

If you need to access user claims, you can have a look at the documentation as well:

- [Advanced usage of authentication and authorization in Azure App Service - Access user claims](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-authentication-how-to#access-user-claims)